# Unable to authenticate with omniauth-instagram, client_id missing

Tags: rubygems, instagram, omniauth

I am authenticating using OmniAuth with both Twitter and Instagram. Twitter is working well.

When I start the authentication process with the /auth/instagram request, OmniAuth is not including the client_id in the authorization header.

I have initialized OmniAuth as:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, ENV.fetch('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'), ENV.fetch('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET')
  provider :instagram, ENV.fetch('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID'), ENV.fetch('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET')
end
```

When I send the /auth/instagram request, it returns:

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", 
 "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"}
```

and shows the request uri without my client_id:

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=&redirect_uri=http://demo.herokuapp.com/auth/instagram/callback&response_type=code&scope=basic&state=952ced9482ccf34faf3e09cffd40f59548f3c5a539499723
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ENV` variables are probably not being loaded in time / after your initializer is loaded. Try replacing them with the actual strings and see if that works. Don't commit that to a public repo... trust me it's annoying to remove if you do.

I am a fan of [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv). I use the `rails-now` version to load ENV vars in initializers.

`gem 'dotenv-rails', :require => 'dotenv/rails-now'` in Gemfile

reference like: `ENV['INSTAGRAM_ID']`